# I would like to copy data to the memory so that you can still paste it even after the spreadsheet is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried the code above, however, if you copy the data from the range and close the spreadsheet, you cannot paste it anywhere. You can only paste the data as long the range is still selected in Excel.

I would like to copy it to the memory so that you can still paste it even after the spreadsheet is closed.

I am making use of Macro's. So for example:

I have 2 tabs in Excel, TAB1 = data tab (contains names / data from A1-A6) 
second TAB is information tab.

I have created a button and Macro to copy the data from TAB1 over to TAB2, then I have created a second macro that needs to copy the data from TAB2 onto a clipboard / memory... This is where I get stuck. I get the copy function to work, but the moment I close the spreadsheet or just double click on a different block, the copied items is out of the memory and cannot be pasted anywhere else.

Comment: `Range(MyRange).copy` works for me (excel 2003), even after closing workbook (but not after double click: the normal behaviour).

Comment: `I have tried the code above` ... above where? there is no code in this post.